# using delay in foreach()

Tags: c#, directory

I have a temporary folder where I have some files, what I want to do is copy one at a time to another folder ( but it has to have some delay between "the copys" ) because for each file I have to do some work with it.
So it will be

1. copy older file from `c:\temp` to `c:\correctFolder`
2. do some work with this file (this is why I need the delay).
3. Copy the next file

My code so far is

```
var sortedFiles = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp").GetFiles()
                                               .OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime)
                                               .ToList();


foreach(var p in sortedFiles) 
{
    File.Copy(@"C:\Temp\" + p, @"C:\correctFolder\" + p);
    //delay
}
```

I can´t use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);` because it will stop everything and I want to delay only the `foreach` so I can work with the file..

Comment: What work do you want to do with the file?

Comment: If you do your work synchronously in the foreach, then I do not think that there is any need for a specific delay, as the processing will happen immediately after the copy, and a new copy will only happen once the processing is finished.

Comment: Why can't you perform your processing logic right here in foreach, after file is copied? If the work is synchronous, i.e. stays on the same thread, next iteration won't occur until it's done.

Comment: I have to integrate in database the info I read from the file and then send it to a scale. I have a fileSystemWatcher_Created that when detects a file will do all the work. So When I copy the file to the folder that is being watched all the work is done automatically

Comment: Is the FileSystemWatcher in the same program/process as the code that does the copy?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why Thread.Sleep won't work for you? That will of course "delay" the program like you want. What exactly is the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do whatever you want with your files in a separate thread. You can use `Sleep` for delay, because "it will not stop everything". Your application will respond and stay cool.

Comment: I did that and I think its working I was using the System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);and created the treath but i forgot to call thread.Start(); ...silly me

Answer (score 2):

If you need to block the next iteration of the `foreach`, just call the code you need to invoke after the copy:

```
var sortedFiles = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp")
                      .GetFiles()
                      .OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime)
                      .ToList();


foreach(var file in sortedFiles) 
{
    var sourceFile = Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\", file);
    var destinationFile = Path.Combine(@"C:\correctFolder\", file);

    File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile);

    SomeOtherMethod(destinationFile);
}
```

The next iteration of the foreach will not execute until `SomeOtherMethod()` has returned.

Comment: As I said I have a fileSystemWatcher_created that do all the work when the file is created is the destination folder so if 2 files are copied at the same time , it will call the fileSystemWatcher_created 2 times in a row. So this solution won´t work, rigth?